# Convert the date from PST to IST and output the difference in hour

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to automatically convert PST Date in to IST date. When I put date in column E and F I have dates in PST time zone. I want to convert in IST time zone. after i want output in column G. the difference between two dates.

I have solved this with excel formula but I want this to done with VBA.

For eg.

```
> E                           F                      G             
1/14/2016  2:49:00 PM     1/14/2016  2:57:00 PM          0:08

1/14/2016  2:45:00 PM     1/14/2016  2:59:00 PM          0:09
```

Comment: Same day-date but only 8 minutes difference, for different timezones?? And in the second line, the difference is 14 minutes not 9. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub qwerty()
   Dim pst As Date, ist As Date

   pst = DateSerial(2016, 1, 14) + TimeSerial(14, 49, 0)
   ist = pst + TimeSerial(13, 30, 0)
   MsgBox pst & vbCrLf & ist
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

String string = "December 16, 2016 12:10:05 PST";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH); 
Date date = format.parse(string);
System.out.println(date);

Output : Sat Dec 17 01:40:05 IST 2016

Comment: Please try to add context around your answer and format the code.